# jQuery .trigger("change") not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't get `.trigger("change")` to work. Anyone know why?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery("select[id='DROPDOWNID']").change(function () {

        var selectedIndex = jQuery("select[id='DROPDOWNID']").prop('selectedIndex');

        switch (selectedIndex) {
            case 0:
                hideVarforProspekt();
                break;
            case 1:
                hideOrdervarde();
                break;
            case 2:

                break;
            case 3:
                hideSektor();
                break;
        }
    });

    ** jQuery("select[id='DROPDOWNID']").trigger("change"); **


    function hideVarforProspekt() {
        jQuery("input[id='IDFROMSHAREPOINT']").closest('tr').hide();
    }

    function hideSektor() {
        jQuery("table[id='IDFROMSHAREPOINT']").closest('tr').hide();
    }

    function hideUppskOrder() {
        jQuery("input[id='IDFROMSHAREPOINT']").closest('tr').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: And I'm the worst when it comes to pasting code, sorry!

Comment: Can you show your `select[id='DROPDOWNID']` html code?

Comment: why are you using attribute selector instead of id selector, it should be `$('#DROPDOWNID')`

Comment: why is it not working

Comment: @ArunPJohny: Because in Sharepoint Online some commands is run with $ so I'm trying to avoid using it.

Comment: @rAjA It worked before, .trigger() stopped working when I put the jQuery commands in functions so why is the HTML code interesting?

Comment: @Robin it is the same as `jQuery('#DROPDOWNID')`

Comment: @Robin without the html we will not be able to do much

Comment: Did you check the element selector 'select[id='DROPDOWNID']' ?
Does jQuery("select[id='DROPDOWNID']").get() return the right element ?

Comment: @Damien Yes. As i said earlier it worked before, before I added the jQuery commands into functions.

Comment: @Robin I just wanted to make sure you have all the values mentioned in your code switch case

Comment: Move all your functions out of document.ready

Comment: @rAjA that didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes the usage of trigger is not necessary:

```
// use just jQuery("#DROPDOWNID") instead
var select = jQuery("select[id='DROPDOWNID']");

// placing the handler in separate function
var changeHandler = function () {
    var selectedIndex = select.prop('selectedIndex');
    switch(selectedIndex) {
        case 0:
            hideVarforProspekt();
        break;
        case 1:
            hideOrdervarde();
        break;
        case 2:

        break;
        case 3:
            hideSektor();
        break;
    }
}

// cache your jQuery selectors. It's a good practice
// and improves the readability
select.change(changeHandler);

// triggering
changeHandler();
```

Comment: This worked when the site was loaded, but not when I change in the dropdown menu. Do you know why?

Comment: Yep, just move the handler above the event attaching http://jsfiddle.net/ccyG8/ (I also edited my answer).

Answer (score 60):

Change event handler should be defined before calling the `.trigger('change')` or `.change()`

**Below are 2 scenarios.**

**Scenario 1:** where change event is called before it is defined.

```
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
       $('#selector').change();   or  $('#selector').trigger('change');
       $('#selector').on('change', function(){

        });
    });
```

**Scenario 2:** where change event handler is defined before calling it

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $('#selector').on('change', function(){

    });
    $('#selector').change();   or  $('#selector').trigger('change');
});
```

For me issue was fixed when I use scenario2. Hope this helps!!

Comment: Great finding Man!! Cheers!

Comment: Great finding Man!! Cheers! Super Man. Thank you so much help me a lot.

Comment: Thanks, I was dealing with the same error. Because I typed .trigger('change') before $('#aaaaaa').on('change')...... , it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working version using the id syntax:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('select[id=car]').change(function () {
      alert("change: " + $(this).val());
  });

  $("#car").trigger('change');
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunkv08/qgPzc/29/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#selector').change();
```

or

```
$('#selector').trigger('change');
```

// 2nd one works for me. But you should call it after the definition of change event

Answer (score 0):

used this :

```
jQuery("#DROPDOWNID").trigger("change");
```

can you please check given link [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/malvaniya_shakti/qgPzc/2/)

HTML Code

```
<select id="car">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

**Jquery Code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#car").change(function(){
    alert("change");
  });

    $("#car").trigger('change');
});
```

**Result :**

It fire alert

Remove **id=** from all selector and replace it with **#selected id**

Comment: It doesn't work when I remove id=. jQuery("select[id='S_x00e4_ljsteg_f9f2bae9-f429-46c6-aa2d-6b126b50056f_$DropDownChoice']").trigger("change");

This worked before, so I dont know why I have to change it.

Comment: used this jQuery("#DROPDOWNID").trigger("change");

Comment: Ah, so you’re using `id='«id»'` syntax because your IDs have characters that require escaping to represent in a CSS ID selector form.

Answer (score 0):

The `.change()` event waits until the input field loses focus, so it won't be fired before you click or tab out of the field.

So you can just add `.blur()` event after the `.change()` event like this:

```
     var $element = jQuery("select[id='DROPDOWNID']");
     $element.change(function () { ... });
     $element.blur();
```

Or you can use another event instead of `.change()`, e.g. `.keyup()`, `.paste()`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised no-one mentions this, but when `jQuery("select[id='DROPDOWNID']").trigger("change")` doesn't do the job (like when trying to emulate change on angular code using Tampermonkey)
`jQuery("select[id='DROPDOWNID']")[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('change'))` does

Answer (score -1):

try this , it should work

```
$('#selector').change();
```