# Select2 - auto selecting dynamic dependent dropdown box

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

In my project, I have 5 dependent dropdown box, and I used select2 pluging for this. I have to select first 3 box automatically by ajax and user will filled the rest two box and if he want can change data of first 3 box's also. But the problem is when I trying to select first 3 box by ajax, sometime's it fail's to select item's which is come from server, but the next field is select properly.

Here is my javascript code -

```
function loadTempAdress(){      // Id of all address field and jquery selector pass here
    $('.division-parma').val(2).trigger('change');
    $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'GetDistricts',
                data: {
                    get_option:2
                },
                success: function(response) {
          $('.district-parma').html(response);
          $('.district-parma').val(42).trigger('change');
          $('.district-parma').val(42).trigger('change');
          $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'GetUpazila',
            data: {
              get_option:42
            },
            success: function(response) {
              $('.upazilla-parma').html(response);
              $('.upazilla-parma').val(67).trigger('change');
            }
        });
     }
  });
```

Here is screenshot of this scenario -
[image]

N.B.: in image, there would be but not by

Comment: Is there data in your selects?

Comment: yes there is data as it it a dependent select, most of the time it got selected, but sometime it failed to select.

Comment: You may triggering your events before handling its events, see the second answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18693463/jquery-triggerchange-not-working