# Javascript trigger Change Suddenly Quit Working

Tags: javascript, jquery

New Edit 04/28/2024:

As it turns out the problem was not with my code.  In this case the website programmers had added some fatal code to the site accidentally which they corrected on the following day.  My apologies for taking so long to get back.

I have been using this line of code on an input box successfully for a decade:

```
var importDate = "03/07/2023";
$("#es-modal-very-important-date").val(importDate).trigger('change')
```

Today it quit working.  It does put the date into the box but it does not trigger the change. So the webpage doesn't recognize the date.  It's like the box requires a user click or interaction with a datepicker to trigger the change.

I also tried the following to trigger the change without luck:

```
var myInput = document.getElementById("es-modal-very-important-date");
myInput.dispatchEvent(new Event("change"));
```

Are there any other options?  I can only think the programmers who built the webpage (for adding records) have changed something that made the trigger stop working.  I don't have access to the programmers.  I use javascript to automate adding about 100 or so records everyday.

I tried the following:

```
var importDate = "03/07/2023";
$("#es-modal-very-important-date").val(importDate).trigger('change')
```

and

```
var myInput = document.getElementById("es-modal-very-important-date");
myInput.dispatchEvent(new Event("change"));
```

I expected it to add the importDate into the input box and then to trigger a change so the web page can recognize the change. It does add the importDate but the webpage does not recognioze it.

Comment: Is this specific to a particular web page?  Browsers do in some cases treat script-initiated events differently than user-initiated ones, but in [this case](https://jsfiddle.net/0g7wd6s4/) the change event does appear to fire when script initiated.   Dispatching a 'change' event (by whatever method) will only do something if the developers attached a function handler to that event.

Comment: There are many, many [questions like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+trigger+change+not+working). [jQuery .trigger("change") not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18693463/215552), for instance.

Comment: Maybe they don't listen on a `change` event anymore but e.g. on `input`.

Comment: @DanielBeck Thank you.  Yes, this is specific to my workplace. I'll try to search for some handler code.  It would generally fall under a search of the element ID, right?  I should also mention there is a datepicker tied to the same input box.  Clicking anywhere on the box automatically brings up the datepicker box.  I think that's the change they made to the web page. I'm desperately want to avoid messing with the datepicker

Comment: "It would generally fall under a search of the element ID, right?"  Not necessarily, no.   But if you know your way around the developer console, you can right click on the element, inspect it in the dev tools, and look for the "event listeners" tab (in chrome) or under Node->Events (in safari).   But that may or may not show you anything useful depending on how they implemented the date picker. (sorry!)

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the only reliable way to set things on basically any webpage (including React apps) is to use `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window.HTMLInputElement.prototype, "value").set`, e.g.:

```
const set = (selector, value) => {
    const input = document.querySelector(selector);
    const nativeInputValueSetter = 
        Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(
            window.HTMLInputElement.prototype,
            "value"
        ).set;
    nativeInputValueSetter.call(input, value);
}

set('#es-modal-very-important-date', importDate)
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort.  It does put the date into the input box but doesn't trigger the change.

Answer (score -1):

Using jQuery, how about trying this?

```
$('#es-modal-very-important-date').change();
```